# how to calculate percent change rate on a multi-date dataframe elegantly?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe, which index is datetime. it contains a columns - price

```
In [9]: df = pd.DataFrame({'price':[3,5,6,10,11]}, index=pd.to_datetime(['2016-01-01 14:58:00', 
'2016-01-01 14:58:00', '2016-01-01 14:58:00', '2016-01-02 09:30:00', '2016-01-02 09:31:00']))
   ...: 

In [10]: df
Out[10]: 
                     price
2016-01-01 14:58:00      3
2016-01-01 14:58:00      5
2016-01-01 14:58:00      6
2016-01-02 09:30:00     10
2016-01-02 09:31:00     11
```

I want to calculate the next return(price percent change rate for some time intervals).

dataframe have a pct_change() function can calculate the change rate.

```
In [12]: df['price'].pct_change().shift(-1)
Out[12]: 
2016-01-01 14:58:00    0.666667
2016-01-01 14:58:00    0.200000
2016-01-01 14:58:00    0.666667
2016-01-02 09:30:00    0.100000
2016-01-02 09:31:00         NaN
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

but, i want the cross date element to be nan

which means, i want `df['pct_change'].loc['2016-01-01 14:58:00']` to be `nan`, because it calculate the pct_change using tomw's data(2016-01-02 09:30:00)

the expected output:

```
2016-01-01 14:58:00    0.666667
2016-01-01 14:58:00    0.200000
2016-01-01 14:58:00         NaN
2016-01-02 09:30:00    0.100000
2016-01-02 09:31:00         NaN
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

i can make a mask to filter those out. but i think this solution is not elegant enough, is there any suggestions?

Comment: If any answer helps, then close the question by accepting the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) by [`DatetimeIndex.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html):

```
s1 = df.groupby(df.index.date)['price'].apply(lambda x: x.pct_change().shift(-1))
print (s1)
2016-01-01 14:58:00    0.666667
2016-01-01 14:58:00    0.200000
2016-01-01 14:58:00         NaN
2016-01-02 09:30:00    0.100000
2016-01-02 09:31:00         NaN
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Would not `apply` be slower than `df.groupby(df.index.date)['price'].pct_change().shift(-1)`?

Comment: @PraysonW.Daniel - My code and your working different, because `.shift(-1)` is in your code applied only once, in my solution it is applied for each group.